# Spawning a new process on node on an headless Raspberry

Tags: node.js, process, raspberry-pi3, headless

I'm currently trying to spawn a process inside my node server to take a screenshot of the only screen attached to my raspberry with this command :

```
var scrot = childProcess.spawn(path.join(__dirname, "bin", "scrot", "scrot"), [options.output]);
```

This command work on my local machine but I get a code 2 response when I try to run it on my headless raspberry under Debian. I suspect it is because my node process is spawned at the beginning of the boot routine, before the x server is started.

The pstree command show me this :

```
systemd─┬─avahi-daemon───avahi-daemon
        ├─bluetoothd
        ├─cron
        ├─2*[dbus-daemon]
        ├─dbus-launch
        ├─dhcpcd
        ├─hciattach
        ├─login───startx───xinit─┬─Xorg───{InputThread}
        │                        └─openbox─┬─openbox-autosta───sh───chromium-browse─┬─ch+
        │                                  │                                        ├─ch+
        │                                  │                                        ├─{A+
        │                                  │                                        ├─{B+
        │                                  │                                        ├─{C+
        │                                  │                                        ├─{C+
        │                                  │                                        ├─{C+
        │                                  │                                        ├─{C+
        │                                  │                                        ├─{C+
        │                                  │                                        ├─{D+
        │                                  │                                        ├─{N+
        │                                  │                                        ├─2*+
        │                                  │                                        ├─3*+
        │                                  │                                        ├─{T+
        │                                  │                                        ├─7*+
        │                                  │                                        ├─{c+
        │                                  │                                        ├─{e+
        │                                  │                                        ├─{g+
        │                                  │                                        ├─{i+
        │                                  │                                        ├─{r+
        │                                  │                                        └─{s+
        │                                  └─ssh-agent
        ├─node───9*[{node}]
```

Is there a way to add a child process to the x server context ?

Thanks for any help in advance,
C.

Comment: Did you try running this script when the Pi is fully booted?

Comment: I am currently running the daemon launching the node server after network services with "After=network.target", i dont know how to launch it after everything is fully booted. Can you tell me how to do so ?

Comment: Just running the node.js script?

Comment: I cant run it alone, the raspberry is configured to be headless and only have a screen attach to it, there is no session other than the auto login one and i configure the rasp using SSH. If i use SSH to launch node and take a screenshot i have the same issue.